# PHP remove duplicated values from array

Tags: php

I have an array with comma separated numbers and I want to remove all duplicated numbers. Is the approach below the best choice or is there a smarter one?

```
$filter_tags_array[] = '4,6,2,5,8';
$filter_tags_array[] = '6,8,1,3,5,7,2,4';
$filter_tags_array[] = '2,4,1,3,5';
$filter_tags_array[] = '6,3,5,8,2,4';
$filter_tags_array[] = '2,8,11,4,9,12';
$filter_tags_array[] = '9,11,2,8,10,12,4';

$tags_id = '';
foreach($filter_tags_array as $filter_tags) {
  $tags_id .= $filter_tags . ',';
}

$tags_id = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $tags_id)));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($tags_id);
```

**print_r results: 4,6,2,5,8,1,3,7,11,9,12,10,**

Comment: The `foreach` loop can be replaced by another `implode` call. `$tags_id = implode(',', $filter_tags_array);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, see here

```
$filter_tags_array[] = '4,6,2,5,8';
$filter_tags_array[] = '6,8,1,3,5,7,2,4';
$filter_tags_array[] = '2,4,1,3,5';
$filter_tags_array[] = '6,3,5,8,2,4';
$filter_tags_array[] = '2,8,11,4,9,12';
$filter_tags_array[] = '9,11,2,8,10,12,4';

$tags_id = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', (implode(',', $filter_tags_array)))));

print($tags_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to implode the array rather than concatenate each string.  This is because php has to create a new string every time.

https://3v4l.org/fUEtn